# Linux GUI for performaing user administration (web or ssh based)

Tags: linux, gui

Does anyone have any references to a tool that can administer Linux users on a remote server using a GUI?

Not a full fledged webmin or cpanel app which requires a clean install, but just a simple tool that can either connect through ssh, or even better connect through a web page and administer the adding, edit, removing, change password of basic user accounts...

Basically just a gui to perform "useradd", "userdel", "passwd" commands , along with a way for someone to view the current users....

I am looking to delegate the task of managing users back to my boss, but anything dealing with ssh causes him to freak ,and even though it is simple, it's impossible for him without some type of gui...

any feedback is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Googling `minimal linux user administration gui`, I found below project is popular and user friendly (hopefully enough friendly for your boss)

[ajenti: admin panel your servers deserve](http://ajenti.org/)
[ajenti: GitHub](https://github.com/ajenti/ajenti)

Note: **ajenti requires installation**, I think due to security concerns, administrating linux remotely through Web UI, installation must be performed by the user.

Technically: its possible to develop GUI that administrate linux through ssh without having anything installed on the target. I found another popular project that seems to apply this concept:

[KeyBox](http://sshkeybox.com/features.html): open-source web-based SSH console that centrally manages administrative access to systems. See below image:

[image]

Comment: ajenti looks promising since it does not require a clean server to install ... It looks like it can slide into an existing server setup without overwriting all the config files ... so I think you found a winner there ... Thank you for the help!

Comment: Danger Will Robinson.  Something that overwrites config files is a Bad Idea (tm).  Far better if it has a means to show you every rewrite it's going to do and asks for confirmation.  In addition, I hope it makes a backup copy.  First rule of sysadmin:  Be able to back out of anything you do.

Comment: that is exactly what I said ... it looks like ajenti does NOT overwrite the config files of the server, therefore a possible option.